# Regex gives weird string back

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

This Javascript regex:

```
homework.description = (homework.input.match(/((\(((\S\s?)\)?)*)|(about( \w*)*))/i));
```

Reading this:

```
potato (potato)
```

Gives this result:

```
(potato),(potato),(potato),o),o,
```

Which is weird.
It should give this:

```
(potato)
```

[Here](http://regexr.com/3aq08) is what it should do.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aH3jV7/1

Comment: @Andreas, that shows nothing new. I am confused.

Comment: Are you trying to win an unnecessarily obfuscated regex contest?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to separate a homework's title and description assuming it's typed in the same field. The examples at the [link](http://regexr.com/3aq08) I provided might help. (I updated them)

Comment: I think that's a very complicated regex for what you are trying to do.  What about this instead?  `/\((.*)\)$|about\b(.*)$/gm`?  http://regexr.com/3aq0b

Comment: Did you read the explanation given in the right upper corner? There are 4 capturing groups. First `(potato)` = complete match, Second `(potato)` = first capturing group, third `(potato)` = second capturing group, `o)` = third capturing group, `o` = forth capturing group. The last two `undefined` values are from the second alternative with `about(...)`

Comment: did you try to add g flag ?

Comment: @EthanBrown, Thanks! Thank worked with a bit of work on my part.

Comment: Even better then what I wanted :P

Comment: Your question would be much better if your sample data was part of your code snippet, and not on another site.  Lots of people assume all unknown links lead to malicious sites, not mention it simply being more difficult because its more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out to work. Credit to @EthanBrown for the simpler regex!

```
homework.description = String(homework.input.match(/\((.*)\)$|about\b(.*)$/i)).split(',')[1]
if(homework.description === null || homework.description === ""){
        homework.description = String(homework.input.match(/\((.*)\)$|about\b(.*)$/i)).split(',')[0]
}
```